# Can't read the content of a certain page of a pdf file available online

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, web-scraping, pymupdf

I've used ***[PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/)*** library to parse the content of any specific page of a pdf file locally and found it working. However, when I try to apply the same logic while parsing the content of any specific page of a pdf file available online, I encounter an error.

I got success using the following script (local pdf):

```
import fitz

path = r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\pymupdf\Regular Expressions Cookbook.pdf'

doc = fitz.open(path)
page1 = doc.loadPage(5)
page1text = page1.getText("text")
print(page1text)
```

The script below throws an error (pdf that is available online):

```
import fitz
import requests

URL = 'https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pdfminer-docs/latest/pdfminer-docs.pdf'

res = requests.get(URL)
doc = fitz.open(res.content)
page1 = doc.loadPage(5)
page1text = page1.getText("text")
print(page1text)
```

Error that the script encounters:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\general_demo.py", line 8, in <module>
    doc = fitz.open(res.content)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 2010, in __init__
    _fitz.Document_swiginit(self, _fitz.new_Document(filename, stream, filetype, rect, width, height, fontsize))
RuntimeError: cannot open b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xd0\xd4\xc5\xd8\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Length 843       \n/Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx\xdamUMo\xe20\x10\xbd\xe7Wx\x0f\x95\xda\x03\xc5N\xc8W\x85\x90\x9c\x84H\x1c\xb6\xad\nZ\xed\x95&\xa6\x8bT\x12\x14\xe0\xd0\x7f\xbf~3\x13\xda\xae\xf
```

***How can I read the content directly from online?***

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am using `doc = fitz.open(stream=bytes_pdf, filetype="application/pdf")` where `bytes_pdf` output is similar to `b'%PDF-1.4\n1'` but still facing issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need to initialize the object with `stream`:

```
>>> # from memory
>>> doc = fitz.open(stream=mem_area, filetype="pdf")
```

`mem_area` has the data of the document.

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. Thanks a lot @Sergio Pulgarin.

Comment: the docs have moved to here: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document

Comment: Does `mem_area` correspond to `res.content` in the OP question ?

Comment: Yes, the data bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example that directly solves the question:

```
import fitz
import requests

URL = 'https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pdfminer-docs/latest/pdfminer-docs.pdf'

res = requests.get(URL)
doc = fitz.open(stream = res.content, filetype="pdf")
doc.get_page_text(pno=0) # read text from first page
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you were missing the **read()** function to read file as bytesIO which pymupdf can then consume.

```
with fitz.open(stream=uploaded_pdf.read(), filetype="pdf") as doc:
    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.getText()
    print(text)
```